# Multiple Aggregations with grouping in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm, aggregation

I'm trying to make a dashboard and I have to use django ORM instead of raw queries, but I cannot find the right equivalent for this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT persons.name, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN work_hours.work_type='A' THEN work_hours.count ELSE 0 END) as additional_hours , 
        SUM(CASE WHEN work_hours.work_type='D' THEN work_hours.count ELSE 0 END) as duty_hours, 
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN work_hours.stat_type='D' THEN work_hours.count ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 
            1.0*SUM(CASE WHEN work_hours.work_type='A' THEN work_hours.count ELSE 0 END)/
                SUM(CASE WHEN work_hours.work_type='D' THEN work_hours.count ELSE 0 END) 
        ELSE -1 END as over_rate 
    FROM daily_work_hours as work_hours 
    inner join personnel as persons 
    on work_hours.person_id = persons.id 
    GROUP BY persons.name 
    order by over_rate desc) stats
WHERE duty_hours>100;
```

can anybody help me with this?